# Is this a sign of some disease or insect damage? (Piel De Sapo plant)

Tags: diseases, pest-damage, melons

I tried doing some research into what might be causing the damage, as the vine is also damaged slightly. I looked around the rest of my garden and the winter melon and hairy melons are growing perfectly. The pumpkins are also growing without a problem, so I am at a loss to why the Piel De Sapo is growing at a sub-par level.

I believe it is some disease but I haven't had any experience with growing this type of melon. There isn't much information online  I'm growing this in Sydney, from a melon I bought at Costco Australia.

[image: Piel De Sapo]

[image: Piel De Sapo Leaves]

[image: Piel De Sapo Leaves and Fruit]

Any ideas? Or is this just basic insect damage? If it is insect damage, then does anyone have any ideas on what I can use to deter these insects?

Comment: This is a virus/fungus/bacteria. Might as well remove the plant as you will not get a good crop from it.

Comment: @kevinsky: your answer is a bit imprecise, depending on the pathogens you'll need to deal different with your plant. And a virus differs from a fungus or bacteria too much.

Comment: @user60000: could you post a photo of the fruit, which is better (sharper) than your first one above?

Comment: Have you bought seeds, or did you take the seeds from a fruit yourself? If the last is the case, than maybe the seeds have been underdeveloped.

Comment: @ChristophMühlmann That's why it's a comment, not an answer. Regardless, for one seasonal outdoor plant it's not worth it to try and return it to good health.

Answer (score 2):

Possibly Alternaria blight, a fungal infection. I can't see the brown parts clearly enough to see whether there are concentric rings within the brown areas, but the spots do appear to have some yellowing around them. This infection can affect the fruits, and occasionally, its the fruit that then infects the plant. If it is Alternaria, you should not grow any curcubit group plants in the same spot for 3 years. It may, on the other hand, just be a fungal leaf spot infection, not actually Alternaria.